# Jquery Stock ticker issue

Tags: jquery

All,

I am using code I found here: http://www.aaronjwhite.org/index.php/15-web-development/jquery/7-using-jquery-and-google-finance-to-create-a-simple-stock-ticker

I am trying to make it work and it does not give me any error message or anything. It just does not do anything.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'> </script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:AIR&callback=?',function(response){
var stockInfo = response[0];
var stockString ='<div class="stockWrapper">STOCK:';
stockString +='<span class="stockSymbol">'+stockInfo.t+'</span>';
stockString +='<span class="stockPrice">'+stockInfo.l+'</span>';
stockString +='<span class="stockChange">'+stockInfo.c+'</span>';
stockString +='<span>at</span> <span class="stockTime">'+stockInfo.ltt+'</span>';
stockString +='</div>';
$('.stockTick').prepend(stockString);
}); });
</script>


</head>
<body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

<form id="form1">

<div class="stockTick">Stock ticker should be here </div> 

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I save it in an .htm file to see if it would work and so far nothing.

Comment: First off, while the document.ready helps you out a bit, it's always good to dump your js just before the close of your body tag.

Comment: Second, use your devtools.  Most browsers have them, and the console is a lifesaver.  Just type in the name of your stockInfo (first), and see what that gets you.  Anything?  Then try the stockString.  Then poke around the .stockTick.  That's how I'd go about debugging this.

Comment: I apreciate your help. I found out what the issue was. I did not copy and paste the person's code properly :-( I was missing a closing statement at the end. "});"  I edited the code above, in case someone would want to use it.

Comment: Seems like it's always the simplest stuff that throws a wrench in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't ended your `$(document).ready(function(){` function:

Add another `});` to the end of the script

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON('https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=NYSE:AIR&callback=?',function(response){
var stockInfo = response[0];
var stockString ='<div class="stockWrapper">STOCK:';
stockString +='<span class="stockSymbol">'+stockInfo.t+'</span>';
stockString +='<span class="stockPrice">'+stockInfo.l+'</span>';
stockString +='<span class="stockChange">'+stockInfo.c+'</span>';
stockString +='<span>at</span> <span class="stockTime">'+stockInfo.ltt+'</span>';
stockString +='</div>';
$('.stockTick').prepend(stockString);
});
});
</script>
```